# how to get data id attr for every post jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to do system comment for every post as facebook, system comment simple but my problem if I do this code I get the data-id value the first post

code jquery

```
$('.reponse').each(function(j){
    $(this).attr('id','reponse_'+j);
});
```

code html+php

```
$stmt = $connect->query('SELECT *FROM publications 
                                                    ORDER BY date_post DESC ');


while($row=$stmt->fetch() )
{?>
    <div class ="reponse" data-id='<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($row['id_post'])); ?>'> </div>
<?php }?>
```

code ajax

```
$('#form_post').on('submit',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();




var query = $('#comments').val();

var queryid = $('.reponse').data('id');
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        data : {commentPost:query,idpost:queryid},
        url : 'traitementCommentPost.php',
        success : function(data)
        {

            $('.fetch_all_comment').prepend(data)  ;        
        }

    });
$('#comments').val('');
});
```

**always i get data-id value the first post**

Comment: Where is your `#form_post`?

Comment: this some code (problem)

Comment: Sorry. Where is your `<form>` tag?